# Hide confirmation header after a POST in a XML and PHP cURL application

Tags: php, curl, twilio-php

After I POST data from my Twilio PHP application using the following cURL code:

```
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

I get a confirmation header from the server where I posted the data. The confirmation header I receive is javascript and it makes my application crash because of a parsing error.

Here's the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play>../audio/en/thankYou.mp3</Play>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>
<!-- confirmation header -->
<script>
    function sizeAllow(uploaded_size){
        return (uploaded_size < 64000000);
    }

    function validAllFiles(myfilename){
         return myfilename == "";
    }

</script>
```

My question now, is there any way to hide the confirmation header that is returned into the application from the external server? Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#refsect1-function.curl-setopt-examples `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);`

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome!  Happy coding.